# iText : UnsupportedEncodingException: Identity-H

Tags: java, itext

I'm trying to use IDENTITY_H font encodinng in my code :

```
BaseFont courier = BaseFont.createFont(BaseFont.COURIER,  BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
  Font font = new Font(courier, 12, Font.NORMAL);
```

Here's the error i get.
Should i add an additionnal jar or what's the problem exactly? 
Thanks

```
ExceptionConverter: java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException: Identity-H
at java.lang.StringCoding.encode(StringCoding.java:269)
at java.lang.String.getBytes(String.java:947)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfEncodings.convertToBytes(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.Type1Font.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(Unknown Source)
at com.lowagie.text.pdf.BaseFont.createFont(Unknown Source)
at fr.srd.core.TextFileToPDF.main(TextFileToPDF.java:35)
```

Comment: Its not a problem of jars.. real problem i mentioned below

Answer (score 8):

you can apply some of the encodings only when you use BaseFont.xxxx as first parameter in createFont method. like  CP1250, CP1252 , CP1257 ,WINANSI ,MACROMAN .

and if you are creating new custom fonts

```
BaseFont baseFont=BaseFont.createFont("C://Windows//Fonts//Arial.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
    Font font=new Font(baseFont, 10);
```

using Type1 font referred to by an AFM or PFM file, a TrueType font then only u can use IDENTITY_H or IDENTITY_V . basically they are encoding styles.

below some references m providing check them.

http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BaseFont.html#createFont%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29

and

http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BaseFont.html#IDENTITY_H